# Limiting <a href> click function

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following set up which when the div is clicked, it brings up a popup container which is based on this (https://github.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay)

```
<div class="outer my_popup_open">
    Main content                  
</div>
<div id="my_popup" style="display:none;">                   
    <div class="Popup content">
        Popup content           
    </div>                  
</div>
<script>
    jQuery('#my_popup').popup({             
        })              
</script>
```

Anyway, I am trying wrap the `outer` div container in an anchor like below:

```
<a href="example.com/go_here">     
  <div class="outer my_popup_open">
    Main content                  
  </div>
</a>
```

Here is the dilemma.

I want to maintain the popup function while having the "right-click: Open link in new tab" option.

Here is what I mean.

So, if user left clicks the div, then it will bring up the popuplayover as it should. However if user right-clicks the div, then there is an option to "open link in new tab" so they can go to the link if they choose to do so. In other words, I want to prevent anchor to be clicked using the left mouse click if that makes sense, thus allowing the popup to function properly.

Is there a way to limit the left click function so that it does not click "anchor link"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping the default event is good. However, in your case, you need to enable different behavior on two different clicks and each time after click you need to reset the behavior back. So, I guess you are looking for something like this.

HTML:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <Title>My Test Document</title>
 </head>
 <style type="text/css">
  a {color:black;}      /* unvisited link */
  a:visited {color:black;}  /* visited link */
  a:hover {color:black;}  /* mouse over link */
  a:active {color:black;}
 </style>
 <body>
  <a id="main_div" style="text-decoration:none;">Tushar</a>
  <div id="pop_up" style="display:none;">
    this is pop up.
  </div>
 </body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $('#main_div').mousedown(function(event) {
  switch (event.which) {
   case 1:
    alert('Left Mouse button pressed.');
    $(this).attr('href','');
    $('#pop_up').toggle();
    break;
   case 2:
    alert('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
    $(this).attr('href','');
    break;
   case 3:
    $(this).attr('href','https://www.google.com');
    break;
   default:
    $(this).attr('href','');
    alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
  } 
 });              
</script> 
</html>
```

Comment: This is really interesting. Now I understand the concept. I am going to give this a try =) Thanks!

Comment: Well, this is interesting. I simply wrapped the div in anchor. Now, it looks like the jQuery function actually has the default anchor click disabled and falls to the popup function. Anyway, I am going to keep this method in mind and use it in the future. Thank you! =)

Answer (score 1):

You should prevent the default click action:

```
jQuery('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // whatever you want to do here
});
```

The variable `e` is the event, the function `preventDefault()` makes sure that instead of passing the click function to the browser, it's only executing whatever code you have wrapped in the listener function.

And of course add a class or id to the anchor, otherwise every link on your page will be listening to the function ;)

Comment: Hmm, i see. I am going to give that a try. =) Thanks

Comment: Thank you for awesome explanation! :)

Comment: I am going to keep this method in mind and use it in the future. Thank you! =)